# How to turn python list comprehensions into xml

Tags: python, xml, list, csv

I need a little help on finding a tutorial or sample on taking a list comprehension and merging that with a data file from csv and turning all that into an xml file. From reading various python books & pdfs like ditp,IYOCGwP, learnpythonthe hardway,, lxml tut, think python and online searches I am most of the way there or so I think. I just need a push on tying everything together. I am basically taking an excel spreadsheet which I am exporting as a csv file. The csv contains rows of records which I need to map into an xml file. I am new to Python and thought I would use my little project to learn the language. The code listed is not pretty but works. I can read in a csv file and dump that into a list. I can combine 3 lists and output the resulting list and I can get my program to spit out a skeleton xml that is almost laid out in the format that I need. I will list my actual output of a small sample and what I am trying to accomplish with the xml below this code. Sorry if this is too lengthy, this is my first post.

```
import csv, datetime, os  
from lxml import etree  
from ElementTree_pretty import prettify

f = os.path.getsize("SO.csv")
fh = "SO.csv"
rh = open(fh, "rU")

rows = 0
try:
    rlist = csv.reader(rh)
    reports = []
    for row in rlist:
        '''print row.items()'''
        rowStripped = [x.strip(' ') for x in row]
        reports.append(rowStripped)
        rows +=1
except csv.Error, e:
    sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (filename, reader.line_num, e))

finally:
    rh.close()

root = etree.Element("co_ehs")
object = etree.SubElement(root, "object")
event = etree.SubElement(object, "event")
facets = etree.SubElement(event, "facets")
categories = etree.SubElement(facets, "categories")
instance = etree.SubElement(categories, "instance")
property = etree.SubElement(instance, "property")

facets = ['header','header','header','header','informational','header','informational']

categories =     ['processing','processing','processing','processing','short_title','file_num','short_narrative']

property = ['REPORT ID','NEXT REPORT ID','initial-event-date','number','title','summary-docket-num','description-story']

print('----------Printing Reports from CSV Data----------')
print reports
print('---------END OF CSV DATA-------------')
print
mappings = zip(facets, categories, property)
print('----------Printing Mappings from the zip of facets, categories, property ----------')
print mappings
print('---------END OF List Comprehension-------------')
print
print('----------Printing the xml skeleton that will contain the mappings and the csv data ----------')
print(etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True))
print('---------END OF XML Skeleton-------------')
```

```
----My OUTPUT---  
----------Printing Reports from CSV Data----------  
[['1', '12-Dec-04', 'Vehicle Collision', '786689', 'No fault collision due to ice', '-1', '545671'], ['3', '15-Dec-04', 'OJT Injury', '87362', 'Paint fumes combusted causing 2nd degree burns', '4', '588456'], ['4', '17-Dec-04', 'OJT Injury', '87362', 'Paint fumes combusted causing 2nd degree burns', '-1', '58871'], ['1000', '12-Nov-05', 'Back Injury', '9854231', 'Lifting without a support device', '-1', '545671'], ['55555', '12-Jan-06', 'Foot Injury', '7936547', 'Office injury - heavy item dropped on foot', '-1', '545671']]  
---------END OF CSV DATA-------------  
----------Printing Mappings from the zip of facets, categories, property ----------  
[('header', 'processing', 'REPORT ID'), ('header', 'processing', 'NEXT REPORT ID'), ('header', 'processing', 'initial-event-date'), ('header', 'processing', 'number'), ('informational', 'short_title', 'title'), ('header', 'file_num', 'summary-docket-num'), ('informational', 'short_narrative', 'description-story')]  
---------END OF List Comprehension-------------  
----------Printing the xml skeleton that will contain the mappings and the csv data ----------  

    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <co_ehs>
      <object>
        <event>
          <facets>
            <categories>
              <instance>
                <property/>
              </instance>
            </categories>
          </facets>
        </event>
      </object>
</co_ehs>

---------END OF XML Skeleton-------------  
----------CSV DATA------------------  
C_ID,NEXT_C_ID,C_DATE,C_NUMBER,C_EVENT,C_DOCKETNUM,C_DESCRIPTION  
1,-1,12-Dec-04,545671,Vehicle Collision,786689,"No fault collision due to ice"  
3,4,15-Dec-04,588456,OJT Injury,87362,"Paint fumes combusted causing 2nd degree burns"  
4,-1,17-Dec-04,58871,OJT Injury,87362,"Paint fumes combusted causing 2nd degree burns"  
1000,-1,12-Nov-05,545671,Back Injury,9854231,"Lifting without a support device"  
55555,-1,12-Jan-06,545671,Foot Injury,7936547,"Office injury - heavy item dropped on foot"  

-----------What I want the xml output to look like----------------------  
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <co_ehs xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="co_ehs.xsd">  
      <object id="3" object-type="ehs_report">
        <event event-tag="0">
          <facets name="header">
            <categories name="processing">
              <instance instance-tag="0">
                <property name="REPORT ID" value="1"/>
                <property name="NEXT REPORT ID" value="-1"/>
                <property name="initial-event-date" value="12-Dec-04"/>
                <property name="number" value="545671"/>
              </instance>
            </categories>
          </facets>
          <facets name="informational">
            <categories name="short_title">
              <instance-tag="0">
                <property name="title" value="Vehicle Collision"/>
              </instance>
            </categories>
          </facets>
          <facets name="header">
            <categories name="file_num">
              <instance-tag="0">
                <property name="summary-docket-num" value="786689"/>
              </instance>
            </categories>
          </facets>
          <facets name="informational">
            <categories name="short_narrative">
              <instance-tag="0">
                <property name="description-story" value="No fault collision due to ice"/>
              </instance>
            </categories>
          </facets>
        </event>
      </object>
    </co_ehs>
```

Comment: What is the rule for the id attribute of object and the event-tag attribute of event? I assume the event-tag is only a counter?

Comment: @ocaso-protal The id attribute of the object is as I understand it the unique id or integer for that record. The next record of that object-type would be equal to or greater than 4. I believe the event-tag is used in a similar fashion, giving a unique id to each event-tag when it is inserted into a rdms. I have been tasked with taking csv files and serializing into xml that conforms to a schema so that ultimately the xml will be fed into an rdms. I am trying to figure out how to iterate through the mappings and insert each one into the tree before generating the entire xml document.

Comment: @ocaso-protal I converted the csv from a dictionary to a list so my goal is to iterate through each mapping and generate the appropriate tags and also iterate through the through the list which is all the csv data and insert the appropriate data item into the tag. Each data item will have a facets, categories, instance-tag, and property.

Comment: @MWR Hi. Is it possible to have the content of the file "SO.csv" ? I would like to take thing from the beginning. Also, what is **etree** from lxml necessary ? Isn't the basic **xml.etree.ElementTree** library enough ?

Comment: @MWR In _<object id="3" object-type="ehs_report">_ , what does the 3 refer to ? The data following concerns the item of C_ID equal to 1.

Comment: @eyquem I am too new to Python to know if the basic xml.etree.ElementTree is enough. I have been going through the lxml tutorials to try and understand. The SO.csv is: ----------CSV DATA------------------  
C_ID,NEXT_C_ID,C_DATE,C_NUMBER,C_EVENT,C_DOCKETNUM,C_DESCRIPTION  
1,-1,12-Dec-04,545671,Vehicle Collision,786689,"No fault collision due to ice"  
3,4,15-Dec-04,588456,OJT Injury,87362,"Paint fumes combusted causing 2nd degree burns"  
4,-1,17-Dec-04,58871,OJT Injury,87362,"Paint fumes combusted causing 2nd degree burns"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. I use lxml, because it's normally better to generate XML with a framework than with strings or a template file.

The attributes of `co_ehs` are missing, but this could easily be fixed with some `set()`-calls. I leave it up to you to do this.

BTW: You can accept the best answer by clicking on the check mark on the left side of the answer

```
import csv, datetime, os  
from lxml import etree

def makeFacet(event, newheaders, ev, facetname, catname, count, nhposstart, nhposend):
    facets = etree.SubElement(event, "facets", name=facetname)
    categories = etree.SubElement(facets, "categories", name=catname)
    instance = etree.SubElement(categories, "instance") 
    instance.set("instance-tag", count)

    for i in range(nhposstart, nhposend):
        property = etree.SubElement(instance, "property")
        property.set("name", newheaders[i])
        property.set("value", ev[i].strip())


# read the csv
fh = "SO.csv"
rh = open(fh, "rU")

try:
    rlist = list(csv.reader(rh))
except csv.Error as e:
    sys.exit("file %s, line %d: %s" % (filename, reader.line_num, e))
finally:
    rh.close()

# generate the xml

# newheaders is a mapping of the csv column names, because they don't correspondent w/ the XML
newheaders = ["REPORT_ID","NEXT_REPORT_ID","initial-event-date","number","title","summary-docket-num", "description-story"]

root = etree.Element("co_ehs")

object = etree.SubElement(root, "object")

object.set("id", "3") # Not sure about this one
object.set("object-type", "ehs-report")

for c, ev in enumerate(rlist[1:]):
    event  = etree.SubElement(object, "event")
    event.set("event-tag", "%s"%c) 
    makeFacet(event, newheaders, ev, "header", "processing", "%s"%c, 0, 4)
    makeFacet(event, newheaders, ev, "informational", "short-title", "%s"%c, 4, 5)
    makeFacet(event, newheaders, ev, "header", "file_num", "%s"%c, 5, 6)
    makeFacet(event, newheaders, ev, "informational", "short_narrative", "%s"%c, 6, 7)

print(etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8", pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: The principle is seducing, but it needs to have libxml2 and libxslt installed, and to know ElementTree enough to be able to use it (well, you'll say it's the same for csv module...). The problem of sophisticated libraries is that they need to be studied for a more or less long time to be used, sometimes for unsophisticated tasks. When one is impatient to get an operating result, it is interesting to know the fundamental tools enough to manage by oneself. All is a question of taste and situation

Comment: You only need to know a little bit of lxml.etree to solve your problem. @MWR started with `etree.SubElement` and I just added the `set()`calls to set the attributes. That's enough. And for the impatient there is always stackoverflow.com ;)

Comment: I have been working with both the solutions given. I understand eyquem's somewhat because I can relate that to a kind of template even though it is not but yours is more robust in that it will work with different csv files and different element order. All I need to do is adjust the headers and order of the set calls. I am currently reading up on Generators as I am not sure if I should create one or more generator(s) or define functions as I still have a lot to learn. Again thanks to you & eyquem.

Answer (score 0):

I created a file with name **'pattern.txt'** and following content (with this indentation).

Notice the 8 `%s` put at strategic places.

```
        <event event-tag="%s">
          <facets name="header">
            <categories name="processing">
              <instance instance-tag="0">
                <property name="REPORT ID" value="%s"/>
                <property name="NEXT REPORT ID" value="%s"/>
                <property name="initial-event-date" value="%s"/>
                <property name="number" value="%s"/>
              </instance>
            </categories>
          </facets>
          <facets name="informational">
            <categories name="short_title">
              <instance-tag="0">
                <property name="title" value="%s"/>
              </instance>
            </categories>
          </facets>
          <facets name="header">
            <categories name="file_num">
              <instance-tag="0">
                <property name="summary-docket-num" value="%s"/>
              </instance>
            </categories>
          </facets>
          <facets name="informational">
            <categories name="short_narrative">
              <instance-tag="0">
                <property name="description-story" value="%s"/>
              </instance>
            </categories>
          </facets>
        </event>
```

I created file **'SO.csv'** with folowing content:

```
C_ID,NEXT_C_ID,C_DATE,C_NUMBER,C_EVENT,C_DOCKETNUM,C_DESCRIPTION  
1,-1,12-Dec-04,545671,Vehicle Collision,786689,"No fault collision due to ice"  
3,4,15-Dec-04,588456,OJT Injury,87362,"Paint fumes combusted causing 2nd degree burns"  
4,-1,17-Dec-04,58871,OJT Injury,87362,"Paint fumes combusted causing 2nd degree burns"  
1000,-1,12-Nov-05,545671,Back Injury,9854231,"Lifting without a support device"  
55555,-1,12-Jan-06,545671,Foot Injury,7936547,"Office injury - heavy item dropped on foot"
```

And I ran the following code:

```
import csv

rid = csv.reader(open('SO.csv','rb'))
rid.next()

with open('pattern.txt') as f:
    pati = f.read()

xmloutput = ['    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>',
             '    <co_ehs xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" '\
             'xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="co_ehs.xsd">',
             '      <object id="3" object-type="ehs_report">']

for i,row in enumerate(rid):
    row[0:0] = str(i)
    xmloutput.append( pati % tuple(row) )

print '\n'.join(xmloutput)
```

Does this help you ?

Comment: @eyquem When I run it I am getting:  xmloutput.append( pati % tuple(row) )
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: @MWR The numbers of **%s** in **pati** must be the same as the number of elements of the tuple present after `pati %` . The string **pati** has 8 %s . The **SO.csv** file has 7 fields and `row[0:0] = str(i)` insert a new element at the position 0 in a read row. I think the first line of your **SO.csv** is `'----------CSV DATA------------------'` so you must skip not only one but two lines in **SO.csv** : `rid.next()` and again `rid.next()` . By the way `lu = rid.next()` is not necessary; I corrected to remove `lu=`

Comment: @MWR I think it should be possible to create the file **pattern.txt** itself, or the string it contains, from the XML skeleton . But I don't know XML.

Comment: @eyquem Thanks, I think I see or am starting to understand. Is the pattern.txt a template file that the %s is being used to populate the value from the iteration? I think it is working and I will keep at it . So if I understand correctly I do not need lxml just the csv library. To write the xml file I created a handle and changed your print statement to fout.write('\n'.join(xmloutput)). Thank you very much, having your example is a great help.

Comment: @eyquem I am new to this stackoverflow and I just tried to give you an upvote but I do not have enough cred yet :( I will try and help others as you have helped me. Right now I just feel more of a newbie and have very little python wisdom to impart but I will keep learning and trying to help others.

Comment: @MWR There are two ways to format a string: one that existed ante Python 2.6 with modulo operator `%` : see _5.6.2. String Formatting Operations_ ; and the new formatting capabilities of Python 3 (included in Python 2.6 whose "major theme was preparing the migration path to Python 3.0"): string method `str.format(*args, **kwargs)` (see _5.6.1. String Methods_) and `Formatter class` (see _7.1.2. String Formatting_) for which is used the 7.1.3. Format String Syntax . I am not very skilled in the new formatting tools, but for common needs, the first one is sufficient. I indeed used it in my code.

Comment: @MWR  I hesitate to call pattern.txt a template, but sure it is a pattern that allows to construct a string by replacing the present 2-chars `%s` in it by successive elements of the tuple written after the modulo operator `%` being after **pati**. It is a rather simple subject, youèll understand by reading the doc, I am sure.

Comment: @MWR _"So if I understand correctly I do not need lxml just the csv library."_ It is what seems to me. There are certainly additional points to settle.  For example, I don't know the numbers that must be in `<object id="3" object-type="ehs_report">` , `<event event-tag="0">` , `<instance-tag="0">`, I wrote the code hastily. Concerning upvote, I don't chase them up, it's pleasing for me to solve problems while learning new things in the same time. You'll upvote in the future , if you think about it one day